# Angular ng-show won't eval correctly

Tags: html, arrays, angularjs, json

So if my JSON array object returns this:

```
"Tools": [
{
  "name": "Submit a Claim",
  "position": 1,
  "isOn": true,
  "alert": null
},
{
  "name": "My Recurring Claims",
  "position": 2,
  "isOn": true,
  "alert": null
},
{
  "name": "Online Enrollment",
  "position": 3,
  "isOn": false,
  "alert": "Online enrollment is available for the upcoming plan year. Click here to enroll!"
},
```

And my ng-show html has this:

```
<div class="toolTile col-md-3" ng-show="Tools.name = 'Online Enrollment' && Tools.isOn==true ">
    <a href="#/claimEnter">
        <img class="toolIcon" src="ppt/assets/toolIcons/oe.svg">
        <p>Online Enrollment</p>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="toolTile col-md-3" ng-show="Tools.name = 'Submit a Claim' && Tools.isOn==true ">
    <a ng-click="transId()" ng-href="{{ ppt.Globals.hasDebitCard ? '#/claimEnter' : '#/claimSub' }}" >
        <img src="ppt/assets/toolIcons/submitclaim.svg" >
        <p>Submit a Claim</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

Why does it keep evaluationing to false? I have tried quite a few variations and the "Online Enrollments" should hide while the "Submit a Claim" should show.

Any ideas of what I may be doing wrong here?

Thanks much.

Comment: forgot a `==`? in `Tools.name = 'Submit a Claim'`

Answer (score 1):

> Hi Man You could not Post Code with Out Head and Tail. There were Some
>   Syntax Errors Which caused the trouble .
>
> You Need to Provide a Plunker with Buggy Code at least for some help :-) .

When you got an array in object you need to iterate over it.

I have provided you a running Plunker :-

```
    <div ng-repeat="tool in data.Tools">
               <div ng-show="tool.name == 'Online Enrollment' && tool.isOn==false ">
                    Online Enrollment
                </div>

                <div ng-show="tool.name == 'Submit a Claim' && tool.isOn == true ">
                   Submit a Claim
                </div>

                </div>
```

Plunker :-

http://plnkr.co/edit/B01pKWLsUtA2JlTAPOd5?p=preview

Good Luck !! Let me Know Your Queries if any !!